# How to print +1 in Python, as +1 (with plus sign) instead of 1?

Tags: python, number-formatting

As mentioned in the title, how do I get Python to print out +1 instead of 1?

```
score = +1
print score
>> 1
```

I know -1 prints as -1 but how can I get positive values to print with + sign without adding it in manually myself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

With [the `%` operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
print '%+d' % score
```

With [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format):

```
print '{0:+d}'.format(score)
```

You can see the documentation for the formatting mini-language [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: Thank you it works, can you explain the formatting logic behind it so I can learn it rather than memorize it ? Thank you.

Comment: @Capriano: The `+` indicates that the number should be formatted beginning with a `+` if it is positive (or a `-` if negative). The `d` indicates that the number should be represented in decimal (base ten).

Comment: Just wondering @icktoofay is score now considered a float/double? (i know in c %d is referring to an int variable.

Comment: @John: No; like C, `f` is for `float`s and `double`s; `d` is for decimal integers.

Comment: If you are not sure what type is your number, use simply: `'{0:+}'.format(score)`

Comment: When using f-string: `print(f'{score:+}')`

Comment: In case you have a float or a scientific notation like ```'{0:.2e}'.format(x)```, the ```+``` comes right after the colon, like ```'{0:+.2e}'.format(x)```

Answer (score 19):

from `python>=3.8+`

```
score = 0.2724
print(f'{score:+g}') # or use +f to choose the amount of decimals
# prints -> +0.2724
print(f'{score:+.3f}') # 3 decimal places 
# prints -> +0.272
```

percentage

```
score = 0.272425
print(f'{score:+.2%}')
# prints -> +27.24%
```

Comment: For integers, ```f'{score:+d}'``` is the way.

Comment: For integers `f'{score:+}'` works too

Answer (score 5):

In case you only want to show a negative sign for minus score, no plus/minus for zero score and a plus sign for all positive score:

```
score = lambda i: ("+" if i > 0 else "") + str(i)

score(-1) # '-1'
score(0) # '0'
score(1) # '+1'
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use this: `['', '+'][i > 0] + str(i)`

Answer (score -5):

```
score = 1
print "+"+str(score)
```

On python interpretor

```
>>> score = 1
>>> print "+"+str(score)
+1
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks ani but yeah as ice explained I needed python to do it for me and not add t manually.