# Is there a better way to produce a delta value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, negative-number, delta

Hi fellow stackoverflow'ers,

I'm pretty good with Python but I'm trying to see if there is a better way to do the following. I need to produce a delta to adjust stock levels. I have the following code which works, but could it be done faster/more Pythonic?

```
a = 100
b = 50

def negativeNumber(x): # From https://stackoverflow.com/a/64445338/22669764
    neg = x * (-1)
    return neg

if not a == b: 
    if b < a:
        delta_qty = negativeNumber(a - b)
    if b > a:
        delta_qty = b - a
    if b == 0:
        delta_qty = negativeNumber(a)
if a == 0 and b == 0:
    delta_qty = 0
```

The above works and produce the following results:

```
b<a = -50
b>a = 50 (If we swapped the values)
b=0 = -100 (If b=0)
a=0 & b=0 = 0 (I need this to set a variable not shown in example)
```

Is there is a faster/tidier/more Pythonic way I would achieve the same results?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers and comments, Goku's answer and Homer512 comment look to achieve what I need in a far neater fashion.

Comment: Do you need negative sign or not in your delta?

Comment: What's up with that `negativeNumber()` function? You can just write `neg = -x`

Comment: Can the current code really work? What would happen if I gave two equal but not zero numbers?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly are you trying to achieve with the results you are producing?

Comment: @MechanicPig The `if not a==b` allows for two equal but non zero numbers, it skips over the need to work things out and carry out a longer step after this bit, it simply moves on to the next item in the loop. We only have to worry about them not being equal or both being zero

Comment: @Homer512, ah... that's what I was looking for, yet googling and stack overflow led me to that page I linked in my example code.

Comment: @JohnGardounis It's to send the correct value to the Shopify GraphQL API, unlike their REST API you cannot say `stock = 10`, you have to say `stock = +10` or `stock = -10`. It feels backward and I only switched from REST as I needed to send another value on conjunction with the stock quantity.

Comment: See this question to understand how to get `"+10"` rather than `"10"` when converting the number to string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337004/how-to-print-1-in-python-as-1-with-plus-sign-instead-of-1

Comment: Thanks @slothrop, adding a `+` in a string is not what I needed at this stage (but I have used something similar for the onscreen output), the issue was needing to get a INT value with a negative when required to send to the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want negative sign (as you have shown in example) in your result then:

```
def your_func(a,b):
    return b-a                   # it will give negative when a > b and vice-versa
```

If you **do not** want negative sign no matter which is bigger a or b then :

```
def your_func(a,b):
    return abs(b-a)
```

---

```
delta_qty = your_func(a,b)
```

Comment: Thanks @Goku, I'll give this a try. In reply to your comment above I do need the negative when `b` is less than `a`. It's for use with the Shopify GraphQL API which unlike their REST API you cannot simply say 'I have 10', you have to say 'I have +10' or 'I have -10' no idea why they felt the need to make life difficult.

Comment: @NebularNerd top one in the answer should work as it will give negative when b<a